# can't access to netcore api in docker image

Tags: .net-core, continuous-integration, forwarding

I'm trying to gain access to a netcore app in a docker container hosted in my vps remotely, but even locally I'm not able to access it.

[image]

As you can see, the app is running in a container and listenning to port 5000 (used default Kestrel config). Why can't I access it ?

Comment: Did you tell docker to map the port? You need to use the parameter `-p` with `docker run`. For example `docker run -p 5000:5000 <your other parameters>`.

Answer (score 0):

What your output above is showing is that port 5000 is open, but you have not mapped anything on your local system to that port.  This means that when you ping localhost on port 5000 it will not forward to the container.

Try running the container again with `docker run -p 5000:5000`  The output of docker ps should show something like `0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp`.